# Converting FFT of an audio signal into MIDI notes in real time

Tags: matlab, real-time, fft, midi, frequency

Well. I am new to FFT and not that much killer in programming. But I need to know, whether it is possible to detect FFT of an audio signal from a microphone, and convert it into corresponding MIDI note in real time. Can this be done using MATLAB?? Please help..

Answer (score 1):

For most common music, transcription to useful Midi is harder to do than you might think. An FFT, which you can compute for your audio data, gives you spectral frequencies, which are very often different from played or perceived pitch.  The real-time response latency may depend on the audio input buffer size and frame size of your chosen FFT, in addition to any other processing time.

Try the MIREX site for a ton of scholarly papers on this topic: http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/MIREX_HOME